# Triangulation trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, triangulation

[image]
I’ve been looking at triangulation calculations, and I’ve become a bit stumped as to how the authors of the attached document have come to the following calculations.

In the page it explains how one can get the slope length for value C-B. I don’t know why they are using the 02 value as this is over 90 degrees and would not be used in trigonometry as it wouldn’t make up one of the internal angles.

Even if they subtracted 90 degrees from this angle to get the angle from north left the opposite and adjacent lengths are reversed. I hope this makes slight sense!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see that $$\tan(\theta_2-90^\circ)=\frac{y_2-y_3}{x_3-x_2}=-\frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}$$
And using that $\tan(\theta_2-90^\circ)=-\tan \theta_2$ we get that $\tan \theta_2=\frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}$

Comment: If we are using 02 minus 90 to get the interior angle of the triangle should we not be using x2-x3/y3-y2?

Comment: @Richard: interior angle is $180^\circ-\theta_2$ but the tangent would still be difference is $y$ coordinates divided by the difference in $x$ coordinates.

Comment: Vasili, thank you so much for the replies and the time taken to help. I don’t know why they have decided to use the angle that they have (02) sorry can’t find correct sign. Rather than not just using tan 180-02 as you did in your calculation. Apologies if this is a basic question!